# Sinhala translation of commentaries and subcommentaries

Tags: theravada

Is there a way to read Sinhala translation of commentaries and subcommentaries online..? 
I found the pali one, but not in Sinhalese.

Hope for a help. Triple Gem Bless you all!!

Answer (score 2):

There are many sites with Sinhala:

- Suttacentral - https://suttacentral.net/si/dn1 (A P de Soyza)
- Buddha Jayanthi can be found in many sites - http://www.sjp.ac.lk/news/download-theravada-tripitaka/ in PDF, http://www.thripitakaya.org/, http://www.aathaapi.org/Thripitaka.html
- Pitaka - http://pitaka.lk/ (A P de Soyza)
- Tipitaka - http://www.tipitaka.org/

http://www.aathaapi.org/Thripitaka.html and http://www.tipitaka.org/ [Atthakatha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atthakatha) in Pali but Singhala fonts. There are for sale translation of some of them at Buddhist Cultural Centre.

Comment: I find no commentaries or subcommentaries in these sites.. Those links contain only Sinhala Tripitaka..

Comment: See: පාළි අට්ඨකථා, පාළි ටීකා in http://www.aathaapi.org/Thripitaka.html and අට්‌ඨකථා, ටීකා & අන්‍ය in http://www.tipitaka.org/sinh/. These a Pali in Sinhala script but not translation. Some translations are available at BCC but the quality of translations maybe poor.